# correct encoding in ecdsa, python

Tags: python, ecdsa

I am following technical instructions how to create a bitcoin wallet.

It says:

```
private_key = 18E14A7B6A307F426A94F8114701E7C8E774E7F9A47E2C2035DB29A206321725
```

1 - Take the corresponding public key generated with it (65 bytes, 1 byte 0x04, 32 bytes corresponding to X coordinate, 32 bytes corresponding to Y coordinate)

```
public_key= 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6
```

and my code in python 3.5.2 :

```
from ecdsa import SigningKey, SECP256k1

private_key = '18E14A7B6A307F426A94F8114701E7C8E774E7F9A47E2C2035DB29A206321725'

x = SigningKey.from_string(private_key, curve=SECP256k1)
print(x)
```

The error:

```
output = ERROR: assert len(string) == curve.baselen, (len(string), curve.baselen)
builtins.AssertionError: (64, 32)
```

I am not really sure what to do, because any manipulation would return different `public_key`. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: See more [Bitcoin Public Key from a Private Key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25024/how-do-you-get-a-bitcoin-public-key-from-a-private-key)

Answer (score 0):

The private key you are using in your example above seems to be in hex format. The function,

```
 from_string(private_key, curve=SECP256k1)
```

takes a string private_key. So instead of passing the hex format private key you must pass it a string version

Below is what I tried and it seems to be working just fine,

```
 private_key = SigningKey.generate(curve=SECP256k1)
 string_private_key = private_key.to_string()
 SigningKey.from_string(string_private_key, curve=SECP256k1)
```

This successfully returns an ecdsa signing key object

```
<ecdsa.keys.SigningKey object at 0x103a53f60>
```